# is it possible to use wp cli to export custom post types

Tags: wp-cli, export, csv

i have been trying to use WP CLI to export custom post type 'product' from custom taxonomy 'product_brand'. however, my command is exporting a random list of products, from other brands. it also is not exporting any variations.

here is my command:

```
wp post list --post_type=product --fields=ID,post_title --tax_query='[{"taxonomy":"product_brand","field":"slug","terms":"dassy"}]' --format=csv --include=children > dassy_products.csv
```

Comment: technically the answer to your question is in the question, yes you can export CPT's, you might want to rephrase it though. I also see variations which heavily implies WooCommerce, you can't ask for help with 3rd party plugins here, unless your question can be answered with generic WP knowledge it's offtopic

Comment: ps: have you tried `--product_brand=dassy`? WooCommerce variations likely needs a question asked in a WooCommerce community, WooCommerce probably has its own WP CLI subcommands too

Comment: thank you will ask woocommerce.